# Creating snippets with quotation marks inside

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some code with quotation marks that I want to use as a snippet. Unfortunately, JSON requires me to use them in `"body"` array in my settings. I tried to use different types of quotation marks, but Visual Studio highlights it in red:
[image]

What can I do to include quotation marks in my snippet?

Answer (score 40):

Use `\` to escape the double quotes.
A sample snippet looks like this:

```
"My quoted snippet": {
    "prefix": "quot",
    "body": [
        "Hello \"User\""
    ],
    "description": "Print snippets with quotes"
}
```

When you execute this snippet it will print: `Hello "User"`

Comment: This doesn't work: `Invalid characters in string. Control characters must be escaped`

Comment: It doesn't work for me too. With other symbols to escape (for example $) \\ (double back slashes) help. But with " even \\ doesn't help.

Comment: Trying to translate some coffescript from Atom (which does handle quotes and double quotes perfectly). This trick  *does* work for me at least in this example:  `"echo \"<pre>\";",`

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping there was a online converter available for this purpose to convert the code to correctly encoded code, but seems noone did that as of yet...

Remember that json also needs escaping with \ so you might have to \ for it to work correctly, an example from [#42669459](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669459/vs-code-snippet-escape-file) has this sollution:

What to encode: ${code}

Sollution:

```
"Return Code With Squirly And Dollar": {
    "prefix": "code_snippet",
    "body" : [
        "\\${code\\}"
    ],
    "description": "Code Snippet"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can simply use `\` (backward slash) if you want to use double quotes or any other thing in json

Example :

```
"print statement":{
    "prefix": "print",
    "body": "print(\"$1\")",
    "description": "print anything in python"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My environment is Visual Studio 2022.

I wanted to create a snippet that produces the following line of code:

```cs
_logger.LogInformation($"")
```

The following worked for me

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>logger information</Title>
      <Shortcut>loginfo</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[_logger.LogInformation($$" ");]]>
      </Code>
      <Imports>
        <Import>
         
        </Import>
      </Imports>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you used **tabs** in your real snippet, but if yes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59115459/3510872) fixed my issue.
You can replace tabs characters by spaces, or maybe use `\t` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone, I found that I getting an "invalid escape character" message but the problem was with a path rather than the double quotes themselves. Here's what I ended up doing and it works fine.

```
"body": "<cfdump var=\"#arguments#\" output=\"C:\\webmx\\www\\myDump.html\" format=\"html\">",
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Wosi 's answer to create a snippet that creates a snippet template.

We covert this:

```json
    "snip": {
        "prefix": "snip",
        "body": [
            ""
        ],
        "description": "Template to create a new snippet"
    },
```

INTO:

```json
    "snip": {
        "prefix": "snip",
        "body": [
            "\"$1\": { "
            "   \"prefix\": \"$1\",   "
            "  \"body\": [   "
            "   \"$2\"   "
            "  ],  "
            "  \"description\": \"$3\"  "
            "},   "
        ],
        "description": "Template to create a new snippet"
    },
```