# VS Code snippet - escape ${file}

Tags: escaping, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'd like to create a snippet in VS Code, which includes exact string `${code}`. However, when I enter it in this form, VS Code tries to interpret it as snippet parameter. How should I escape it properly?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

"}" AND "$" can be escaped with "\\".
Some cases "$" can be escaped with "$$" but not in your case.

Your snippet should look like this.

```
"Return Code With Squirly And Dollar": {
    "prefix": "code_snippet",
    "body" : [
        "\\${code\\}"
    ],
    "description": "Code Snippet"
}
```

This should help you

Comment: An ES6 string literal example: `"console.log(\`${1:debugEl}: \\${ ${1:debugEl} \\}\`)"`